# setting a dropdownlist value from database on page load

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ddl

Sounds like an easy job but havent been able to figure it out.I have an edit profile page where all the user data is pulled from database to respective textboxes,labels etc on Page_Load.The dropdownlist is binded to a table as below.My ddl is as below :

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" Width="160px" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBound="ddlGender_DataBound">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

and is binded as below :

```
protected void BindGenderDropDown()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblGenders", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlGender.DataSource = ds;
        ddlGender.DataTextField = "GenderName";
        ddlGender.DataValueField = "GenderId";
        ddlGender.DataBind();
    }
    ddlGender.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
    ddlGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I am not able to set a value in the dropdownlist though.Here is what I have done :

```
 private void ExtractData()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fgff"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblRegPlayers1 where UserId='PL00011'", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string path = rdr["ProfilePicPath"].ToString();
            hfImagePath.Value = Path.GetFileName(path);
            txtFName.Text = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
            txtEmailAddress.Text = rdr["EmailAdd"].ToString();
            txtContactNumber.Text = rdr["MobileNo"].ToString();
            txtdob.Value = rdr["DOB"].ToString();
            txtStreetAddress.Text = rdr["StreetAddress"].ToString();
            txtZipCode.Text = rdr["ZipCode"].ToString();
           ddlGender.Items.FindByText(rdr["Gender"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

But it says 'Object is not set to an instance'. So i played around a bit and tried doing it in DataBound like this :

```
    protected void ddlGender_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblRegPlayers1 where UserId='PL00011'", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            ddlGender.Items.FindByText(rdr["Gender"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Now it doesnt throw any error and it doesnt select the value as well.

PS : 1.I have set Autopostback true for the ddl.
2.I am aware of sqlInjection and have made changes to make it look simpler.

My final PageLoad looks like this :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //btnReset.Visible = false;
        ExtractData();
        BindDisabilityDropDown();
        BindGenderDropDown();
        BindStateDropDown();
    }
    if (hfImagePath.Value == "" || hfImagePath.Value == "0")
    {
        imgCropped.ImageUrl = "~/ProfilePictures/DefaultProfilePicture.png";
        hfImagePath.Value = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        imgCropped.ImageUrl = "~/ProfilePictures/" + hfImagePath.Value;
    }
    //lblRegistration.Text = Session["Button"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the ASP.NET code for `ddlGender`? Just for sake of seeing what's there for events and such.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" ....></asp:DropDownList>` part, but the code you added is useful as well.

Comment: Please post the code in your `Page_Load` handler.

Comment: @Kirk Yes.I have pasted that too.

Comment: @MikeC - Obviously,I put my ExtractData() in page load.Which set of code are you talking about?

Comment: @RelatedRhymes Post the actual handler so we can see what you're doing and how those methods are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you are calling `ExtractData` before you have actually bound the `DropDownList` in the `BindGenderDropDown` method.  This means that your dropdown will have no items when you try to look it up and set the selected item.  First things first you need to move the databinding code above `ExtractData`.

Second, you are you trying to set the selected value in an unusual way.  Instead of attempting to `FindByText` you should try setting `SelectedValue` instead.

I will assume that the contents of `rdr["Gender"]` in `ExtractData` is the `GenderId` you have bound to the dropdown, and not the display value in `GenderName`.  I will also assume that `GenderId` is `M` and `F` and `GenderName` is `Male` and `Female` (although if your actual implementation varies slightly then that's ok).

Try changing:

```
ddlGender.Items.FindByText(rdr["Gender"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

To:

```
ddlGender.SelectedValue = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
```

Also be sure to remove the code you have added for the `DataBound` handler, it is not necessary here.

Comment: Oh yes.I just realized my mistake of calling ExtractData before DataBind.So when i run it it still gives me an error 'Cannot have multiple selections for a dropdownlist'.So I deleted the 'ddlGender.SelectedIndex = 0; '  line from BindGenderDropDown() and now it works fine. However,your answer is still acceptable.Thank you.

Comment: You are likely getting this by trying to set `Selected` manually.  By using the method I suggested, you will avoid the issue introduced by `SelectedIndex = 0`.  Using `SelectedValue` and `SelectedText` will handle properly updating the `Selected` property on the individual items.

Comment: Yes, I further corrected my code by using 'ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["Gender"].ToString(); '..since rdr["Gender"] contains a text too.And I am now keeping 'ddlGender.SelectedIndex = 0;' in BindGenderDropDown as well.So, it is all working fine now.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
ddlGender.DataSource = ds;
ddlGender.DataTextField = "GenderName";
ddlGender.DataValueField = "GenderId";
ddlGender.DataBind();
```

You are trying to set the value to a specific Column, yet you are binding it to a DataSet and not a DataTable. (A DataSet has no columns only DataTables).

Try the following assuming the DataSet has a table returned and the column names match your table structure:

```
string strDesiredSelection = "Male";    
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
ddlGender.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddlGender.DataTextField = "GenderName";
ddlGender.DataValueField = "GenderId";
ddlGender.DataBind();
foreach(ListItem li in ddlGender.Items){
    if(li.Value.Equals(strDesiredSelection)){
        ddlGender.SelectedIndex = ddlGender.Items.IndexOf(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want me to try the above in BindGenderDropDown() ? and what about my selection.Do i do it in ExtractData() on pageload or DataBound event?

Comment: @Related Rhymes - Apologies, I was referring to the section of code in BindGenderDropDown(). And as far as setting the selection you can do it after the list is DataBound. But your DataBound event handler doesn't appear to be necessary. I edited the above just to give you an alternate option.